# Why is this putExtra passing a String instead of an int?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass an R.drawable id to another activity through an intent. I'm using a switch to find the correct drawable and then using putExtra() to pass it. But when I call getIntExtra it says I passed a String. Is there a problem with this code or is it somewhere else?

```
int i = getExerciseId(((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.fragTextView)).getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LevelActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("exerciseId", ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.fragTextView)).getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("image", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public int getExerciseId(String s) {
            int i = -1;
            switch (s) {
                case "Weather":
                    i = R.drawable.weather;
                break;
                case "Weekend":
                    i = R.drawable.weekend;
                break;
                case "Hobbies":
                    i = R.drawable.hobbies;
                break;
                case "Music":
                    i = R.drawable.music;
                break;
                case "Family":
                    i = R.drawable.family;
            }
            return i;
```

edit: there's no log error, I get a red line message in the code saying:

```
getIntExtra(String, int) in Intent cannot be applied to (String)
```

in this line of code:

```
intent.getIntExtra("image");
```

Comment: Please post the error message (log output) and the code where you are extracting the extra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not telling you that you are getting a string, but that you are calling the `getIntExtra` method with insufficient parameters. Call it with

```
getIntExtra("image", 0); // or whichever default value you want to use.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)
```

You have to give a default value to the method call. If the key is not found, the default value is returned.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I thought I checked the guide earlier, but it was for getStringExtra.

Answer (score 1):

for getting int value

```
 //wirte name=imge and defaultValue =-1
 //and have a check if value for image is -1 then no value was received

 intent.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue);
```